# VBA loop through columns - if inside for

Tags: vba, excel

What is wrong with this code? It is supposed to return header (1st row) of a column in which it finds "1". I pass the row number (nr) and it is supposed to look between columns M and T (inclusive)

```
Function who(ByVal rowNr As Integer) As String
    Dim temp As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With ActiveSheet
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(.Name)
    End With
    For i = 13 To 20 Step 1
        If ws.Cells(i, rowNr).Value = 1 Then
            temp = temp & " " & ws.Cells(i,1).Value
        End If
    Next i
    who = temp
End Function
```

The error I get is

> Application-Defined or Object-Defined
>   error

And marks line

```
If ws.Cells(i, nr).Value = 1 Then
```

I truly dislike VB.

Comment: 1) How is it VB's fault that you're unable to write code that works? 2) You should give your variables descriptive names. `bla` is therefore not a good choice.

Comment: @Cody-Gray If vars were in german you would read them as bla anyway. In code I use normal names - here will be bla ;) I'm working in C#/Java/Obj-C so yeah.. VB is really unfriendly.

Comment: Also, I looked into solving your problem, but it appears you don't write questions any better than you write VBA code. The paragraph above the code block just kind of trails off into...

Comment: Have you been able to debug the code? Do you know in which line it hangs?

Comment: And not necessarily; I took several years of German in school. But more importantly, you speak German so you could translate them. It's useful for people reading your code (let's see...who might that be?). For loops are fundamentally the same in all of those languages. So are variable declarations, object assignments, return values, and pretty much everything else you've gotten wrong. Yes, I judge programmers who blame the language rather than themselves quite harshly. Deal with it.

Comment: The fact that I dislike VB doesn't mean I blame it. Question is simple and written as 1st sentence of post. You're getting some bonus points for writing in thread where you don't really wanna help? If I use variable here like ONCE (besides declaration) then I don't think u need any specific name for temporary variable.

Comment: No bonuses for me. I'm not the one with code that doesn't work. Although if I were you, I'd step through it with the debugger and see which line it is that's causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `nr` is used as a numerical value, why are you sending it in as a `String`. Try changing that to an `Integer` and you should be a bit further along at least.

Edit: I forgot that I think you might have mixed up rows/columns as well. I think maybe you want it to be:

```
If ws.Cells(nr, i).Value = 1 Then
```

Comment: Ok, my bad, thx for pointing this out :) It removes error but still doesn't return the value from 1st row of the column where it finds "1".

Comment: @SuperMario: Not sure if you wrote your comment before or after my edit, but if before, please see my other suggested code change as well.

Comment: No no, nr is row name and for columns M to T from this row I want to find 1 and return the 1st cell of column (add to string "who").

Comment: @SuperMario: Did you change the indexing to (row, column) both places in your code? `ws.Cells(i,0).Value` should be `ws.Cells(0,i).Value`. And if `nr` is row name (which is *another* good reason to name your vars descriptively), then this isn't going to work. The `Cells` property requires *integers* that describe indices of the rows and columns, not strings.

Comment: Wow, ok that helped. Cols/Rows are opposite. I messed it cuz once it's "A1" (col/row) and in this case I needed Cells(row/col).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
Function who(ByVal rowNr As Long) As String
    Dim temp As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    For i = 13 To 20 Step 1
        If ws.Cells(rowNr, i).Value = 1 Then
            temp = temp & " " & ws.Cells(1, i).Value
        End If
    Next i

    who = Trim(temp)

End Function
```